# Facebook iOS application Crashing

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios10

Can anyone help me to report a bug in facebook's iPhone application. I want to send the report to Facebook. Any help appriciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: Forms to report broken features can be found in Facebook’s Help section.